# Pass function as an argument in APL

Tags: function, function-pointers, argument-passing, apl

How do I pass a function as an argument?

The basic idea is something like this (which doesn't work):

```
∇R ← double a
R ← 2 × a
∇

∇R ← a applytwice f
R ← f f a
∇

5 applytwice double
```

Is there something like `\fun` in erlang or function-pointers in C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In APL, functions may not be passed as arguments to functions. However, APL has operators, which are higher order functions, that can take functions as arguments. There are primitive operators like / (reduction) used for example to sum up a vector +/v.  The function + is the left operand and is passed into the operator /.

In Dyalog APL, there is a primitive operator using the (named "power") for apply a function n times so we can write:

```
      double←{2×⍵}
      (double ⍣ 2) 7
28
      (double ⍣ 10) 7
7168
```

You can also write your own operators (in most APLs). In Dyalog APL we can write your applytwice operator as:

```
     applytwice←{⍺⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵}
     double applytwice 7
28
```

Finally, you can pass functions around by putting them in a namespace and passing the namespace around instead. This is like a very light weight instance of class with a method. For example:

```
       s←⎕NS ''
       s.f←{2×⍵}
       ApplyFTwice←{⍺.f ⍺.f ⍵}
       s ApplyFTwice 7
28
```

In this case, the function has to be named f, but we could many different functions named f, each in its own namespace.

Comment: Thanks to you ample answer, I figured out how to define operators in GNU APL (simply adding some parentheses). Looks like in APL there is a strict distinction between operator and function, and "operator" refers to functors.

Answer (score 5):

Your applytwice was not that far from correct.  In Dyalog APL and possibly others, the non-dfn (legacy function definition) code would look something like this:

```
       ∇ R ← (f applytwice) a
  [1]   R ← f f a
       ∇

       - applytwice 42
  42

       {2×⍵} applytwice 42
  168
```

In APL, any "program" which accepts zero, one, or two data arguments is a "function".  Built-in functions such as + - etc. might be called "primitive functions".  The double function in the examples would be a "defined function".  An "operator" accepts functions and data as arguments.  +/ and +\ are examples of the reduction and scan operator, + is the function left argument for the / or \ operator.  By contrast, the compress and expand functions use the same symbols (/ and \ ) but have a left data argument.

Such is the APL nomenclature.

Comment: Do you know the dyadic form of legacy higher ordered functions?

Comment: ∇ R ← a (f higher g) b // the same idea, dyadic with respect to both data and functions.  Invoked like 42 (+ higher -) 13

Answer (score 0):

You can also get around this by *quoting*. You can pass a char array and then execute it within the function. This string might contain the name of a defined function or a direct definition.

Comment: A good solution which would work on nearly all APL implementations, from IBM APL.SV (ca. 1970) and up.  APL\360 (1968) didn't have execute, but everything that came later did.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing it directly, pass a QUAD CR of a function as an argument, then QUAD FX it inside your calling function